# Geolocation not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

Am trying to add geo location functionality to site using google geocode as fallback, so far it works properly with chrome.
When i try it out in firefox it doesn't it only shows the location prompt
Heres my code

```
function add_location() {
        if (navigator.geolocation)  
        {  
            $("#pheed-location").fadeIn();
            $('.loading-indicator').fadeIn();
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(handle_geolocation_query, handle_location_errors);  
        }  
    }
    function parseLocationError(error)
    {
        switch(error.code)  
        { 
            case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
            errorMsg = "User did not share geolocation data";  
            code = 1;
            break;  

            case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE: 
            errorMsg = "Could not detect your current position";
            code = 2;
            break;  

            case error.TIMEOUT:
            errorMsg = "Retrieving position timedout";  
            code = 2;
            break;  

            default:
            errorMsg = "Unknown error";  
            code = 0;
            break;  
        }
        var _error = {"msg":errorMsg,"code":code};
        return _error;
    }
    /**
    * Handles error from geolocation
    * @param error object
    **/
    function handle_location_errors(error) {
        var msgDisplay = $('.loading-indicator');
        //Error message
        var errorMsg ="";
        console.log(error);
        //Set error message base on error code
        var Error = parseLocationError(error);
        if((Error.code === 1) || (Error.code === 2)) {
        msgDisplay.html('').fadeOut();
        msgDisplay.html(Error.msg).fadeIn();
            if(Error.code === 2)
            $("#location-entry").fadeIn();
        }
    }
```

I add the "console.log(error)" to ensure the error are being returned. The errors are logged properly in chrome, but dont seem to work at all in firefox.
What could be the problem?

Comment: What version of Firefox? Do any errors show up in the Firebug console? Have you already denied location access to your site?

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL no firebug does not display any errors, i've firefox access to location data

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL am using firefox 11

Answer (score 0):

I've been playing with the geolocation API for the past couple of days and found intermittent problems between Firefox 17/18, Chrome 24.0, Safari 5.1 and IE 9.0. Yesterday it was working perfectly in Firefox but then started to fail. It would prompt for authorisation to share my location, but then nothing. No further code executed... it just died. I tried IE9 and it told me GPS wasn't supported. I tried in Safari, and it also failed. Chrome was the only browser that seemed to still work.

I tried rebooting my laptop. I turned off/on my wireless network on the laptop (Dell XPS 1330). I tried checking the settings for each browser, but I couldn't determine the problem... until...

**SOLUTION:** I rebooted my broadband modem. I am running a DGND3700 (600Mbps Dual Frequency ADSL2+ broadband modem / gigabit router). I performed a remote "Reboot Router" and voila! Everything now works again. I did notice that the connection speed before reboot was 3500kbps (3.5Mbps), but after a reboot it shot back up to nearly 16000kbps (16Mbps!).

If you are experiencing geolocation issues - reboot your wireless router (if you can)! Hope this helps.

Comment: quite strange solution for me

Answer (score 0):

Most probably this is the website fault - it cannot be opened using HTTPS protocol which is required for geolocation detection (https://www.thesslstore.com/blog/firefox-55-https-for-geolocation/).